# how to get the calling application application.properties value into the shared library in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am writing the springboot reactive logging shared library which is used by different spring boot applications.
I would like to print the application.name(of the calling application) which is defined in the application.properties of the calling application into my shared library.
How can i get the values defined in the calling application application.properties file into my shared library.
Appreciate your great help.